# how to get the selected value immediately when an option in a select element is chosen?

Tags: jquery, html, onclick

I want to show something correspondingly as soon as a user chooses an option in a select element in html. So I need to get the selected option value immediately via jquery when a user makes his choice. My jquery is as follows(pretty simple):

```
   $('select').live('click', function(event){
            console.log($('select').val());
        });
```

But the problem is, every time I click the select element, it will show the current value of it first, and then show the value you choose when you click an option, which is not what I want. I don't need the current value, I just want the value you choose this time. So how should I achieve this in jquery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should listen to the `change` event, and use `this` keyword in your handler which refers to current select element, if you have more that one select element in your page `$('select').val()` only returns value of the first select element in your page. Also note that `live` method is deprecated, if you want to delegate event, you can use `on` method instead.

```
$(document).on('change', 'select', function(event){
    console.log( this.value );        
    // console.log( $(this).val() );
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Change it into Select box change event. Try the below code

```
$('select').live('change', function(event){
            console.log($(this).val());
        });
```

(Or)

```
$('select').change(function(event){
                console.log($(this).val());
            });
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
 $('select').change(function(event){
         console.log($('select').val());
    });
```

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Su4rH/)**

Answer (score 0):

You can get the selected value like this :

```
$('#select').change(function() {
        var selectVal = $('#select :selected').val();
    });
```